# SQLAlchemy - Using Relationships to filter by class of row type

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relationships

Below there is a pseudo Many-to-Many table structure of say a customer ordering an event.  What I would ideally like to be able to achieve is do implicit queries and sets by using the different relationship names.

For example (presume that the **init** code creates the associated objects)

```
order=order()
order.events.corporate.name = "Big Corp"
```

This would set the event.type (enum) to "corporate" and the event.name to "Big Corp".  Similarly.

```
print session.query(Order).filter(order.events.corporate.name == "Big Corp")
```

This would only find the event record that had the associated event.type = "corporate". (Trivial example and not necessary but you get the idea)

Similarly using order.events.personal.name would set/query the corresponding records with event.type = "personal"

Your help in understanding what is the best way of achieving this functionality would be much appreciated.

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Order(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'order'
    id                  = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    event_id            = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('events.id'))

    events = relationship("Events")

class Events(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'events'
    order_id            = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('order.id'), primary_key=True)
    event_id            = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('event.id'), primary_key=True)

    corporate = relationship("Event")
    personal  = relationship("Event")
    event     = relationship("Event")

class Event(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'event'
    id                  = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type                = Column(Enum('corporate', 'personal', name='enum_ev_type'))
    name                = Column(String(32))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLAlchemy do not understand the case when relationship is used in filter. In your example `order.events.corporate`.

I've got the following exception while trying to do so:

```
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Order.events has an attribute 'corporate'
```

I would suggest to consider using [AssociationObject](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html#association-object) pattern described in [SQL Alchemy Relationships documentation page](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html).

So the query would be:

```
session.query(Order).filter(and_(EventsAssoc.type=="corporate",Event.name=="Big Corporation"))
```

See full example how to define schema and create objects.

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, orm
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship



metadata = MetaData()
Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata = metadata



class Event(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'event'
    id                  = Column(Integer, Sequence("event_seq"), primary_key=True)
    name                = Column(String(32))
    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(name=\"%s\",id=\"%s\")" % (self.__class__.__name__,self.name,self.id)


class EventsAssoc(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'events'
    id                  = Column(Integer, Sequence("events_seq"), primary_key=True)
    left_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('order.id'))
    right_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('event.id'))

#    order_id            = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('order.id'), primary_key=True)
#    event_id            = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('event.id'), primary_key=True)
    type                 = Column(Enum('corporate', 'personal', name='enum_ev_type'))

    event = relationship(Event, backref="order_assocs")

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(events=%r,id=\"%s\")" % (self.__class__.__name__,self.event,self.id)


class Order(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'order'
    id                  = Column(Integer, Sequence("order_seq"), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(127))
    events = relationship(EventsAssoc)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(name=\"%s\",id=\"%s\")" % (self.__class__.__name__,self.name,self.id)


db = create_engine('sqlite:////temp/test_assoc.db',echo=True)



#making sure we are working with a fresh database
metadata.drop_all(db)
metadata.create_all(db)


sm = orm.sessionmaker(bind=db, autoflush=True, autocommit=True, expire_on_commit=True)
session = orm.scoped_session(sm)

o = Order(name="order1")
ea_corp = EventsAssoc(type="corporate")
ea_corp.event = Event(name="Big Corporation")

ea_pers = EventsAssoc(type="personal")
ea_pers.event = Event(name="Person")


o.events.append(ea_corp)
o.events.append(ea_pers)
session.add(o)
session.flush()

query = session.query(Order).filter(and_(EventsAssoc.type=="corporate",Event.name=="Big Corporation"))

for order in query.all():
    print order
    print order.events
```

Here is the query produced by sqlalchemy:

```
SELECT "order".id AS order_id, "order".name AS order_name 
FROM "order", events, event 
WHERE events.type = ? AND event.name = ?
('corporate', 'Big Corporation')
```

PS To enhance the association object pattern such that direct access to the EventsAssoc object is optional, SQLAlchemy provides the [Association Proxy extension](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html)

Comment: Thanks vvladymyrov.  It took me a while to circle back to this.  In the end although this would have worked just not in the style I was hoping for I resorted to setting hybrid properties.